# How to determine the added value of installing a (pseudo-)package vis-à-vis installing only one of its dependencies?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

Suppose that (pseudo-)package `A` depends on (pseudo-)package `B`.

I'm looking for a reasonable systematic way to answer the question: "what would I get by installing `A` that I would not get by installing `B` alone?"

To put in the most abstract terms, I want to determine the difference between `A`'s and `B`'s dependency graphs.

Is there a convenient way to do this with standard `dpkg*`, `apt*`, `aptitude*` tools?

---

Since I'm interested in as general an answer as possible, I'm reluctant to give a concrete example (such examples tend to elicit answers that apply only to the example and not to the general case), but inevitably someone posts a comment asking for a concrete example, so here it goes:

`A` could be `task-xfce-desktop` and `B` could be `xfce4`.

Or `A` could be `xfce4` and `B` could be `xfdesktop4`.

---

EDIT: clarification (in response to Stephen Kitt's answer): I am indeed interested in the differences between the absolute dependency graphs (irrespective of the current state of my system).

Comment: I hadn't realised you'd edited your question; in future, please comment on the answer, that ensures the person who answered is notified.

Answer (score 3):

I'll detail two approaches, one which analyses changes which would be made to a system, the other which analyses full dependency trees.

## Changes made to a system

Assuming you're interested in the changes that would be made to your current system, and not the "absolute" dependency chains, you can simulate the installation of both packages and compare the results:

```
(comm -3 <(apt-get -s install A | awk '/^Inst / { print $2 }' | sort) <(apt-get -s install B | awk '/^Inst / { print $2 }' | sort)) 2>/dev/null
```

This asks `apt-get` to simulate (`-s`) installing `A`, and filters out the list of packages which would be installed (the second item in lines starting with `Inst`); it does the same with `B`, sorts both lists and compares them with `comm`, discarding any packages in common (`-3`). The final redirection of `stderr` to `/dev/null` discards `apt-get`'s extraneous output if any (but you won't see any errors).

With you example of `xfce4` and `xfdesktop4`, this produces (on my system, which has neither installed)

```
gtk2-engines-xfce
libkeybinder-3.0-0
libxfce4panel-2.0-4
libxfce4ui-2-0
libxfce4ui-utils
orage
pavucontrol
thunar
thunar-volman
xfce4
xfce4-appfinder
xfce4-notifyd
xfce4-panel
xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin
xfce4-session
xfce4-settings
xfwm4
xscreensaver
xscreensaver-data
```

There's only one column, the left-most one, so this is the list of packages which installing `xfce4` would install on my system, beyond those which installing `xfdesktop4` would install. If you pick `A` and `B` such that neither depends on each other, you'll get two columns, the first showing `A`'s unique dependencies, the second showing `B`'s unique dependencies.

## Full dependency trees

This can be adapted to work on the full dependency tree instead, by using `apt-rdepends`. To get all the unique packages which package A depends on (directly or indirectly, including pre-dependencies):

```
apt-rdepends A | awk '/^  .*Depends/ { print $2; }' | sort -
```

This ignores any version constraints, but that shouldn't have too much incidence in this context.

Thus:

```
comm -3 <(apt-rdepends A | awk '/^  .*Depends/ { print $2; }' | sort -u) <(apt-rdepends B | awk '/^  .*Depends/ { print $2; }' | sort -u)
```

lists all the dependencies of A and B, and lists those that differ (dependencies unique to A in the left-hand column, dependencies unique to B in the right-hand column).

Running this on `xfce4` and `xfdesktop4` again gives

```
adwaita-icon-theme
dconf-gsettings-backend
dconf-service
desktop-file-utils
glib-networking
glib-networking-common
glib-networking-services
gsettings-backend
gsettings-desktop-schemas
gtk2-engines-xfce
hicolor-icon-theme
libasyncns0
libatk-bridge2.0-0
libatspi2.0-0
libcairo-gobject2
libcap2
libcolord2
libcroco3
libdconf1
libdrm2
libegl1-mesa
libepoxy0
libflac8
libgbm1
libgnutls30
libgtk-3-0
libgtk-3-bin
libgtk-3-common
libgudev-1.0-0
libhogweed4
libical1a
libidn11
libjson-c2
libjson-glib-1.0-0
libjson-glib-1.0-common
libkeybinder-3.0-0
liblcms2-2
libnettle6
libogg0
libpolkit-gobject-1-0
libpopt0
libproxy1v5
libpulse0
libpulse-mainloop-glib0
librest-0.7-0
librsvg2-2
librsvg2-common
libsndfile1
libsoup2.4-1
libsoup-gnome2.4-1
libsqlite3-0
libstdc++6
libudev1
libupower-glib3
libvorbis0a
libvorbisenc2
libwayland-client0
libwayland-cursor0
libwayland-egl1
libwayland-egl1-mesa
libwayland-server0
libwrap0
libxaw7
libxcb-dri2-0
libxcb-dri3-0
libxcb-present0
libxcb-randr0
libxcb-shape0
libxcb-sync1
libxcb-xfixes0
libxfce4panel-2.0-4
libxfce4ui-2-0
libxfce4ui-utils
libxkbcommon0
libxkbfile1
libxklavier16
libxmu6
libxpm4
libxshmfence1
libxt6
libxtst6
orage
thunar
tzdata
x11-xkb-utils
xfce4-appfinder
xfce4-panel
xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin
xfce4-session
xfce4-settings
xfdesktop4
xfwm4
xkb-data
```

You can tweak the options to `apt-rdepends` if you wish to include "Recommends" or "Suggests" (see the `-f` option).

Comment: Your `comm` command works because of Bash's "process substitution" feature? Otherwise, `comm` will not read both files from stdin.

Comment: @Shuzheng yes, that’s how it works, note the `<(...)`.