# How to get all URLs for packages that would be installed for `apt install <pkg>` command

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I want to see all URLs that for packages that would be downloaded for `apt install <pkg>` without actually installing the package.

Normally, the URLs can be extracted from the screen output after installing the package (as above).

An example of a URL I want to list:
http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/nmap/nmap-common_7.70+dfsg1-6_all.deb

Is it only possible to get such list of URLs beforehand by looking through all the `apt`'s package source lists?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/72270

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apt install` has a `--print-uris` option which does exactly that:

```
$ apt install --print-uris libreswan
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libcurl3-nss
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcurl3-nss libreswan
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,255 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,584 kB of additional disk space will be used.
'http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/pool/main/c/curl/libcurl3-nss_7.64.0-4_amd64.deb' libcurl3-nss_7.64.0-4_amd64.deb 335908 MD5Sum:376a45e2415e9aea88f5c8825dba0697
'http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libr/libreswan/libreswan_3.27-6_amd64.deb' libreswan_3.27-6_amd64.deb 919276 MD5Sum:cc05b89c596bcf40ac16a9e9fd4185b9
```

It lists all the packages which would be downloaded, with their URI, the target file name, the file size and hash.

Note that files which are already present in your local APT cache won’t be listed.

Comment: Nice, may I ask the following also: is it correct that `dpkg` cannot list such information, since it only deals with installs of local .deb packages (already downloaded), where as the purpose of `apt` is to fetch packages from sources and install them using `dpkg`? Also, do you know if `apt` automatically deletes downloaded packages after installation, since I cannot find the `nmap` packages under `/var/cache/apt`?

Comment: Also, how do you see this `--print-uris` option? `man apt` doesn't list it - I'd also like to get a list of all dependencies (e.g. the "additional" packages that will be installed).

Comment: Yes, `dpkg` doesn’t deal with repositories, so it can’t list download URIs. `apt` does indeed automatically delete packages after installation. The option is documented in `apt-get`’s manpage. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/261336/86440) for commands to list all a package’s dependencies.

Comment: @Shuzheng - a `apt-get install nmap` should not delete downloaded files from `/var/cache/apt` after install.  Some GUI tools (like Synaptic) may or may not, not sure since I don't use them.  Also some cron task may be cleaning up previously downloaded package archives.

Comment: @ivanivan the question here is about `apt`, which does delete downloaded files.